# Error Unit test symfony

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, symfony

When I try to execute this unit test 
I have a problem 
so this is my function testErrors
                                                                     .

```
    public function testErrors(){

    $client = static::createClient();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/add');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('save')->form(array(
    'user[firstName]'      => 'test1',
    'user[lastName]'       => 'test',
    'user[email]'          => 'test@gmail.com',
    ));
    $crawler = $client->submit($form);

    //  3 errors
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('.error_list')->count() == 3);
    // Error firstName field
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('#firstName')->siblings()->first()->filter('.error_list')->count() == 1);
    // Error lasName field
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('#lastName')->siblings()->first()->filter('.error_list')->count() == 1);
    // Error email field
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('#email')->siblings()->first()->filter('.error_list')->count() == 1);

}
```

I have this problem

InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty                   .

this is my Controller

```
   /**
 * @Route("/add", name="addPage")
 */
public function AddAction(Request $request)
{

    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('email', TextType::class)
        ->add('firstName', TextType::class)
        ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Add'))
        ->getForm();


    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


    $firstName = $form['firstName']->getData();
    $lastName = $form['lastName']->getData();
    $email = $form['email']->getData();
    $user->setFirstName($firstName);
    $user->setLastName($lastName);
    $user->setEmail($email);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
    $this->addFlash('notice','user added' );
    return $this->redirectToRoute('listPage');
    }
```

Comment: which statement/line give this error?

Comment: and why you expect that the form get 3 validation error when don't have any  constraint?

Comment: Error in this line "" )); "" so in this statement                                      $form = $crawler->selectButton('save')->form(array(
    'user[firstName]'      => 'test1',
    'user[lastName]'       => 'test',
    'user[email]'          => 'test@gmail.com',
    ));

Comment: and I will to add a constraints for fields

Comment: so you expect the test will fail, ok, correct.

Comment: So what  I have to change ?

Comment: before accessing the crawler, check that the request went fine with something like `$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());` after `client->request`

Comment: It works normal

Answer (score 1):

I think it's your `selectButton('save')` what gives you the error. Try it with your button label `Add` instead of `save`

Comment: On which line? 
let's try separating the statements to track down your error to something like this:
```
        $button = $crawler->selectButton('Add');
        $form = $button->form();
        $form->get('form[firstName]')->setValue('test1');
        $form->get('form[lastName]')->setValue('test');
        $form->get('form[email]')->setValue('test@gmail.com');
```
Also I'm using 'form' as the fieldnames selector because for me that's how it's rendering the form.